# How to transform a list of weights, given that they must sum to 1 and obey bounds?

Tags: python, math, optimization, statistics, weighted

Suppose I have some weights `[w_1,w_2,...,w_n]` and I have the following conditions:

1. `a < w_i < b` for each *i*
2. `w_1 + w_2 + ... + w_n = 1`

Is there a way to transform (squeeze) my original weights to obey these rules?

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Comment: Well if `b < 1/n` I think there is no way to transform the weights so they obey the rules (assuming `a` is positive)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
def transform_weights(weights):
    if not weights:
        return []
    weights_sum = sum(weights)
    return [x/weights_sum for x in weights]

weights = [2, 4, 1, 3, 10]

print(transform_weights(weights))
```

Output:

> [0.1, 0.2, 0.05, 0.15, 0.5]

Answer (score 0):

The conditions may fail to be compatible, and there can be different ways to cope:

- declare "no solution",
- relax type 1 or type 2 constraint,
- compute a "best fit" by assigning a penalty to a constraint that is not fulfilled.

Divide every `w` by the sum of all `w` to achieve the condition 2. Then if you are lucky, the conditions 1 may hold by chance.